# ASP.NET 'Validation of viewstate MAC failed'. error SOMETIMES on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's a personal-site on goDaddy. The aspx/cs exist on a sub-folder of the root directory ('httpdocs/test'). It seems as though, if the button is clicked immediately, there is no error. If there is a 60/120 second waiting period until the button is clicked, the exception is thrown every time.

From many comments that I've seen on StackOverflow & other sites, webfarm or cluster may be confused on where to the PostBack to should return to.

I never get any exceptions thrown, when clicking on the button when tested here my 'localhost'.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

`default.aspx`:

```
<%@ page inherits='visits' codefile='visits.cs'  %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form runat='server'>
            <asp:button runat='server' onClick='clickMe' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`visits.cs`:

```
using System;

partial class visits:System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs ea)
    {}

    public void clickMe(object o, EventArgs ea)
    {}
}
```

I would expect to be able to click that button at anytime, from now to eternity, without a 'Server' exception popping up *occasionally*.

This was obviously a stripped-down version of a more elaborate page/application.  This is about as simplistic/succinct derivation of the actual page that I can present to my friends at StackOverflow.

I'm just confused.  I assume that I could attempt a try/catch on the Javascript button click. I'm not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Add following link in your web.config file.

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" />
```

Above line should be included within section.

OR

if you don't want this solution to implemented on project level then you can add these attribute to the page(Top most line of HTML view) directive of the page which is creating issue.

That means you have to add enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" in page directive.

Hope this helps!